# Unable to Return RGB Colors (CGPoint, CGImage)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The program runs but unfortunately I'm unable to figure out why it is not returning RGB. Could anyone possibly tell me what could be wrong? The crosshair (CGPoint) is panning over the image taken from camera and is showing that the gestures are working on the Xcode console but no RGB is being returned successfully.

I am unable to figure out what the issue may be regarding my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photosButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var crosshair: UIImageView!
    var cameraView2: CGImage?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        addPanGesture(view: crosshair)
        //crosshair.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5)
        crosshair2 = crosshair.frame.origin
        print("viewDidLoad")
        view.bringSubviewToFront(crosshair)
      }
    
    var crosshair2: CGPoint!
      
      func addPanGesture(view: UIImageView) {
          let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(sender:)))
          view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
          print("addPanGesture")
      }
      
      // Refactor
      @objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
          print("handlePan")
          let fileView = sender.view!
          switch sender.state {
          case .began, .changed:
              moveViewWithPan(view: fileView, sender: sender)
          default:
              break
          }
      }
      
      func moveViewWithPan(view: UIView, sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
          let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
          view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + translation.x, y: view.center.y + translation.y)
          sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
          print("moveViewWithPan")
      }
    
    @IBAction func tappedCameraButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let cam = UIImagePickerController()
        cam.sourceType = .camera
        cam.allowsEditing = true
        cam.delegate = self
        present(cam, animated: true)
        print("tappedCameraButton")
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        cameraView?.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("imagePickerController")
    }
    
//extension UIImageView {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor? {
        cameraView2 = cameraView.image?.cgImage
        guard let cgImage = cameraView2, let provider = cgImage.dataProvider
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let pixelData = provider.data
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
        let screenWidth  = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int (screenWidth) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4
        
        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let color = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                return(color)
    }
}
```

It runs but displays an error in the console when I open up the camera saying:

```
2021-01-13 21:01:25.113734-0500 RGB Returner[17055:4324721] [Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your math is off for a couple of reasons.  First, iOS renders in points and not pixels.  So when you ask UIScreen for its size, its giving you points, while your image is in pixels.  See [UIScreen.main.scale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale) for how to convert.  Second unless you are guaranteeing that your image (not your image view, but the actual image inside of it) is exactly the same size as the screen, you need to covert the points to image space.  Also CoreGraphics uses cartesian coordinates (up is positive Y), while UIKit uses inverse cartesian (positive Y is down). Third, the pitch per line in an image is not always on a 32 bit boundary (it usually is but you shouldn't assume it.  use the [bitmapInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454200-bitmapinfo) property to figure out the bytes per row.  Given how complicated all of this is I suggest you start with a very simple 4 pixel image with 4 distinct colors and make sure you can get the correct colors out first, then generalize your solution.